# Custom Android Studio code template

Tags: android, templates, android-studio, freemarker, code-templates

I am tying to write a custom code templates for android studio. I know it can be done using FreeMarker. I am very new to this and have a very basic knowledge of FreeMarker. I want to create a code template where the template.xml file will have input parameters generated dynamically on button click. Is it possible to do that? And can anyone suggest a nice blog where I can explore a lot about FreeMarker.

Comment: see this link https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/idea-live-templates

Comment: Hi @Nilesh thanks for the response. I am not talking about the live templates. Its android code template.

Comment: Yes here is the link for it:
http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/resources-and-tools/6845-android-adt-template-format-document.html
if you find anything dynamic template genration let me know.
I'm also finding this but could not able to track the correct link.